# Bugs in OrderByOn property in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: mysql, ms-access

The setup is a mySQL database on a remote server, using MS Access 2010 as front-end user interface.

Problem occurs in forms based on underlying sorted queries, where default view is Continuous Forms:

- OrderByOn property is False by default – not a problem.
- User turns on OrderByOn property, using a button which re-sorts records (OrderByOn = True) – not a problem.
- User then wants to use original underlying query sort order, using a button that turns off OrderByOn (OrderByOn = False) – there is a problem.  Subsequent requeries of the data do not update the form.  It appears that the ability to requery the data gets switched off, along with the OrderByOn function.
- Problem appears non-trival in that the OrderByOn property does not seem to utilize the underlying mySQL indexes.  A significant performance penalty thus seems to be incurred if OrderByOn cannot be switched off, except when absolutely needed.

Comment: Does MySQL have any SQL trace tools? It would be useful to know what Jet is sending to MySQL. Perhaps you could turn on ODBC logging.

Comment: Are you using ODBC linked tables?

Comment: to @David-W-Fenton's point yes MySQL does have SQL Log. see [MySQL Docs -- The General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) Note the second sentence *"The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients."*

Comment: Do the ordering in server side instead of client side by using "select ... order by .." in the form query instead of using orderby property of the form. This will make use of the index.

Comment: I think this is correct behavior as specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173174(v=office.11).aspx

Basically it should not requery the data when you turn this feature to off.

What do you use to requery the data?

Answer (score 1):

I hooked up a continuous form to an Address Book in Outlook... played around setting the ordering by right-clicking on the fields and choosing A-Z..   I presume that has the effect of setting OrderBy and OrderByOn...

I pressed CTRL-G to get the Immediate Window up...

Entered:

```
?Me![Address Book].OrderBy
```

and got something like this in return...

```
[Public].[Address Book].[Display Name], [Public].[Address Book].[Email]
```

Then I ran the command

```
Me![Address Book].OrderBy = ""
```

and the forms reverted back to their natural underlying order... no need to touch OrderByOn... ??